# Lerna Monorepos and Travis-CI

Tags: travis-ci, travis-ci-cli

I need to setup `Travis` in a monorepo, 
I couldn't find resources.

How can I setup the npm deploy for every package?

Comment: What are you using to manage your mono-repro?  For example, [Lerna](https://github.com/lerna/lerna#readme) @Hitmands

Comment: did you find answer to this?

Comment: I ended up with a full docker environment, my travis is only supposed to start my multi stage build process. But not, I didn’t find anything helpful so far.

Answer (score 2):

To setup a [lerna](https://lernajs.io/) repository with [travis](https://travis-ci.org):

Using:

```
$ node -v
v10.14.2
$ npm -v
6.4.1
```

With the structure:

```
packages/
  foo
    index.js
    package.json
    package-lock.json
  bar
    index.js
    package.json
    package-lock.json
package.json
package-lock.json
lerna.json
.travis.yml
```

`package-lock.json` must be included for all packages.

#### `package.json`

```
{
  "name": "my-project-name",
  "scripts": {
    "postinstall": "lerna bootstrap",
    "test": "my-testing-script",
    ...
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "lerna": "^3.7.1",
    ...
  }
}
```

NPM script `postinstall` to set up the packages before running script `test`. Some people install the package globally, but since you already installed it locally, you don't need to.

Since this is the main `package.json`, you can put all the dependencies in `dependencies`.

The `package.json` for the packages can be configured as you need.

#### `lerna.json`

```
{
  "packages": [
    "packages/*"
  ]
}
```

The file can be configured however you need.

#### `.travis.yml`

```
language: node_js
node_js:
  - "10.14"
script: npm run test
```

Here you can configure the testing environment the way you need.

In my case, I needed to transpile some files with babel and I used `before_script` to run this process before the testing script is run.